# Linq-to-SQL with SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I am working on a small application that is using Linq-to-SQL to access a SQL Server database. The requirement is to write tests using SQL Server CE to test the application.

In the past, I created tests using SQL Server CE with Entity Framework and it's straight forward due to support of SQL Server CE in Entity Framework that allows `.sdf` file creation based on the entities.

Is there any way to achieve the same for Linq-to-SQL, too? To be very specific, I want to achieve something like this using Linq-to-SQL:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.DefaultConnectionFactory =
                new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
using (var sqlCeContext = new EntityFrameworkContext())
{
    sqlCeContext.Database.Create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DataContext class has a CreateDabase method, that you can use. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx